# Difficult issue with subdomain cookies - how to handle writes/read in redirects

Tags: http, cookies, subdomain

I'm using Perl for this but I'm not sure that matters here, this is raw HTTP.

I have various services which I've built a central login for.  The services can be run off-site by third parties and I handle all the handshakes securely, with the central site always maintaining login state with sessions and session cookies.

The problem I'm having is that I want to provide a single login tracker across services in my own domain space, such as *service1.example.com*, *service2.example.com*, etc, but the session cookies aren't "sticking" to the subdomains as intended.

From *example.com* (or *www.example.com*), I'm setting:

```
Set-Cookie: SESSION=12345; domain=.example.com; path=/;
```

Then redirecting to the intended service subdomain.

The cookie is NOT being seen at *service1.example.com*, *service2.example.com*, ... Because the browser is not SENDING the cookie to those subdomains.

Everything I've read indicates this should work, but it doesn't and I can't do a multitude of parameter passing between host names as a means to transfer session state, it needs to be done as a cookie shared across subdomains.

This doesn't appear to be a browser issue.

Can anyone shed some light on what may be going on?

Comment: Does this happen for all browsers?

Comment: Is the cookie seen on example.com or www.example.com? Did you check the browsers debug console or call a simple script just dumping the %ENV to see if your scripts on the subdomains might have a problem? Maybe you set a cookie with the same name directly on a subdomain and your parser allows only one cookie per name?

Answer (score 1):

Check you header capatibility. I check on my site header

```
Set-Cookie: sid=z2weVI8nHMp5upZaoyacr6KhR0BnYs57; Version=1; Domain=.domain.com; Path=/; expires=Tue, 07 Dec 2010 10:48:53 GMT
```

and it brings `sid` cookie to subdomain `forum.domain.com`